# Problems with jquery sexy post, javascript response and placeholder attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm currently working on a rails app in which I have a form which is submitted with jquery sexy post and gets back a js response, the code below was working fine but after I added the placeholder attribute for some reason it got broken.

```
= form_for [@room, @room.messages.new], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    = f.text_area :text, :size => "60x1", :class => "field", :placeholder => "say something"
    = f.submit "Send"
    = f.file_field :image, :class => "img_field"
  = link_to "Add Image", "#", :id => "add_imgLink"
```

The form is being submitted and we get the answer back from the server, though, the js response is not being executed and the form is not being refreshed, any idea what of what could be possible going wrong ?

Thanks!

--
UPDATE:

Just find out that if I replace :placeholder by :value, it does works, but if I don't include :value it doesn't.

UPDATE2:

I found the problem and it wasn't related with jquery, rails or js, one of my coworkers modified sexypost and introduced a bug. Problem fixed.

Comment: Yeesh. I hope this doesn't lead to a slew of `sexy`-prefixed plugins. I've already had it with '<plugin>_fu`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the space in the string.  Try url encoding it.